How to compare total number of occurrence vs the number that are a specific criteria?
I have a dataset where names are separated by gender for articles. Each article is given an index number, so it looks something like this:



Index
Name
Gender
Role




1
A
M
Quoted


1
B
M
Quoted


2
C
M
Quoted


2
D
F
Quoted


2
A
F
Mentioned


3
E
M
Quoted



So all index 2 are for the same article, and names can be repeated between articles. I'm trying to see the relationship between the number of people quoted/mentioned in each article and how many are female. So maybe a scatterplot? To show as more people are included in articles, there is more chance of it being a female or vice versa.
I tried this:
data %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  count(name) %>%
  tally()

but it generates a dataset without any gender, so how do I then make a plot including it?
when I do this:
data %>%
  group_by(index, gender) %>%
  count(index)

it generates M and F in each index separately but how do I make a plot to compare total names in each index against no. of females? Does it even work this way?

count doesn't require group_by, it has it built in. You can do data |> count(index) to get the number of rows for each index. data |> count(index, gender) to get the gender counts for each index and gender, data |> count(index, gender, role) to get the gender counts for each index and role, etc.

Using scatterpie library seems like a good option for this comparison.
read.table(text= "Index     Name    Gender  Role
1   A   M   Quoted
1   B   M   Quoted
2   C   M   Quoted
2   D   F   Quoted
2   A   F   Mentioned
3   E   M   Quoted", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> data

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

data %>% 
  count(Index, Gender) %>% 
  mutate(DummyY = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) -> data_tally

ggplot() +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = Index, y = DummyY, r = 0.45),
                  data = data_tally, cols = c("F", "M")) + 
  coord_equal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = test$Index) +
  scale_fill_discrete("Gender") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())



Another option:
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data ----------------------------------------------------------------
my_data <- starwars %>% 
  filter(!is.na(gender)) %>% 
  select(name, gender, films) %>% 
  unnest_longer(films) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(role = sample(c("quoted", "mentioned"), 1)) %>% 
  ungroup()


# Data wrangling ----------------------------------------------------------
my_plot <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(films = fct_rev(fct_infreq(films))) %>% 
  count(films, gender, role) %>% 
  mutate(
    gender_role = paste0(gender, " ", role),
    n = if_else(gender == "masculine", -n, n))


# A possible plot ---------------------------------------------------------
my_plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = films, y = n, fill = gender_role)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(-35, 35)) + 
  labs(x = "Films (or articles)", y = "People") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(15 * -2:2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Genders and roles",
    values = list(
    "feminine mentioned"  = "red",
    "feminine quoted"     = "darkred",
    "masculine mentioned" = "blue",
    "masculine quoted"    = "darkblue")) +
  egg::theme_article() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 9/16)


Created on 2024-05-03 with reprex v2.1.0
